# How to add core instance group json configuration in emr cluster using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-emr, terraform-provider-aws

AWS EMR allows overriding the cluster configuration for a particular instance group. Terraform also has a [resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/3.74.3/docs/resources/emr_instance_group) to create the task instance group and include your own json configuration for that instance group. But I want to do the same for core instance group but it doesn't have its own separate resource instead it gets provisioned with the aws_emr_cluster. How to configure core instance group configuration or is there something that I am missing?